# Calculating last 8 weeks (summarized data) in Access 2007

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have tried a number of different ways to go about it but am still stuck. I am able to calculate the past 8 weeks (business days) by using the following SQL:

```
SELECT [Returns Data].[Returns]
, [Returns Data].[Return Reason]
, Count([ Returns Data].[Account]) AS [CountOf Account]
, Sum([Returns Data].Amount) AS SumOfAmount 
FROM [Returns Data] 
GROUP BY [Returns Data].[Returned in System]
, [Returns Data].[Return Reason] 
HAVING ((([Returns Data].[Returned in System]) 
  Between (DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),-39)) And Date()));
```

My guess is to manipulate the date serial to get it to last 8 week summary. Ideally I would like the past 8 weeks to be rolling as data gets put into main table.

Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need Date Serial

```
SELECT [Returns Data].[Returns], [Returns Data].[Return Reason], 
    Count([ Returns Data].[Account]) AS [CountOf Account], 
    Sum([Returns Data].Amount) AS SumOfAmount
FROM [Returns Data]
GROUP BY [Returns Data].[Returned in System], [Returns Data].[Return Reason]
HAVING [Returns Data].[Returned in System] BETWEEN Date() AND Date()-39;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use a regular where clause, not the having clause. I you were to filter based on your counts or sum, then you would use the having clause. In this case, a regular where clause will do just fine.

Secondly, what you're looking for is the dateadd function, instead of dateserial.

Something along those lines will probably fix your issue:

```
SELECT [Returns Data].[Returns]
, [Returns Data].[Return Reason]
, Count([ Returns Data].[Account]) AS [CountOf Account]
, Sum([Returns Data].Amount) AS SumOfAmount 
FROM [Returns Data] 
WHERE ([Returns Data].[Returned in System] BETWEEN
DateDiff("ww", -38, Date()) AND Date())
GROUP BY [Returns Data].[Returned in System]
, [Returns Data].[Return Reason] ;
```

Comment: If it worked for you, kindly consider upvoting my answer. Thanks.